# How to know which rows were skipped after loading data file in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

After executing the following command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file.csv'     
     INTO TABLE  mydb.tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

mysql workbench's output console printed the following:

> 14935 row(s) affected Records: 14981  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 46
>
> Warnings: 0

The question is, how on earth do I find out which rows were skipped?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL: Display Skipped records after LOAD DATA INFILE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746436/mysql-display-skipped-records-after-load-data-infile)

Comment: actually, it's a shame to be forced to create a new table, import everything and then dump and then diff with the input file to get an information that could be easily generated by the import tool